# If there's no /dev/md* and not /proc/mdstat, is it safe to use a second disk as a second disk?

Tags: debian, raid

There's two HDs in this server.  I don't see an md device (see title) or an mdstat file.  So, can I be safe that the second disk is currently unused?

Yes, I do want/need the second disk as space much more than RAID-"safety", in case you're wondering.

OS is Debian sid (aka unstable).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to check if the drive is being used as an md raid device (and just not currently active), the only safe way to do it is to run `mdadm -E /dev/sdX`

However if you dont care about whats on the drive (if youre going to wipe it anyway), then it doesnt matter either way.